# ¿La función cin. getline() no funciona bien dentro de bucles?

Tags: c++, bucles

Este es un fragmento del código:

```
void menu()
{
    bool mainLoop;
    char name[50];
    clearConsole(); // Clear console in unix-like os and Windows.
    printTitle("Instance.inc", 2, false);
    do
    {
        std::cout << "\nEnter your name: ";
        std::cin.getline(name, 50, '\n');
        mainLoop = inputName(name); // Function to allow only alphabetic chars
    } while (mainLoop);
}
```

Entonces, pasa que tengo la función inputName que verifica que no halla ningún numero o que tenga al menos 3 carácteres, la cosa es que la primera vez que se ejecuta el código todo funciona perfecto, pero cuando se repite el ciclo, se cumple la función de si la cadena está vacía sin dejar que el usuario escriba el nombre antes.

Luego le vuelve a preguntar al usuario su nombre, pero ya ha saltado el mensaje de que el usuario no ha escrito nada antes, la cosa es que con std::cin << name; funciona perfecto, pero necesito capturar nombres completos.

**EDIT:** Función input name.

```cpp
bool inputName(char *name)
{
    /*Get one name as an argument and validate if is there
    numbers in the string, if so, send an error message
    for input a number in a alphabetic string*/
    char *blankName = name;
    std::string nameLen;

    removeSpaces(blankName);
    nameLen = blankName;
    if (nameLen.empty())
    {
        // Print an error from a list of errors
        errorMsg(7); // Error. You should input something
        return true;
    }

    nameLen = name;
    for (int i = 0; i < nameLen.length(); i++)
    {
        if (std::isdigit(name[i]))
        {
            errorMsg(6); // Error. Only input numbers
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: El código que muestras aparenta estar correcto. Creo que deberías mostrar la función `inputName( )`, o, mejor aún, presentar un [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Si tienes otras funciones que leen la entrada, es mejor que los conviertas también a `getline`. Por supuesto, no uses `char [];` usa `std::string`, y `std::getline` en luego de `cin.getline`.

Comment: tenes que hacer un clearen el loop cin.clear();

Comment: @n.m.ןoṵɐdsǝᴉɯɐןƃǝɹɹɐ La única otra función que lee entradas es la de pedirle si quiere repetir el programa. Con respecto los de char [ ]; necesito recorrer el nombre para remover los espacios en blanco y verificar que no halla numeros, y no sé si se puede manipular con std::strings

Comment: "La única otra función que lee entradas es la de pedirle si quiere repetir el programa" Pues se usa `getline`? Debe usarla. La otra posibilidad es usar cin.ignore como [aquí](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Comment: Hola, me gustaria un ejemplo de la entrada y la salida, y la salida esperada. Y creo que hace falta la funcion remover spacio

Comment: No veo ningun error en tu codigo: [try online-cpp](https://www.online-cpp.com/87UGhs2ZaL) Solo consegui el error de que quita el espacio en el nombre, pero ese error realmente es mio por lo que no lo considero tu error y no veo porque arreglarlo

Answer (score 0):

intenta agregar std::cin.clear(); en el loop para resetear el flag.

```
void menu()
{
    bool mainLoop;
    char name[50];
    clearConsole(); // Clear console in unix-like os and Windows.
    printTitle("Instance.inc", 2, false);
    do
    {
        std::cout << "\nEnter your name: ";
        std::cin.getline(name, 50, '\n');
        mainLoop = inputName(name); // Function to allow only alphabetic chars
        std::cin.clear(); //resetear flag.
    } while (mainLoop);
}
```

Comment: Lo he intentado pero no funciona, hace exactamente lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

También tuve el mismo inconveniente pero en mi caso debía realizar con arreglos y con tipo string. Lo solucione con cin.ignore(); antes de iniciar el bucle for.
Adjunto un ejemplo que soluciona getline en bucles.

```
int x, repetir;
char cliente[10][500];
//string cliente[10];
    
do{
    system("cls");
    cout << "\nNumero de elementos a registrar \"Max 10\": "; cin >> x;
    cout << "\n";
    
    if (x>0 && x<=10){
        cin.ignore();
        for (int i=0; i<x; i++){
            cout << "Ingrese el elemento # " << i+1 << ": "; 
            cin.getline(cliente[i],500,'\n');
            //getline (cin, cliente[i]);
        }
        cout << "\n";
        system("pause");
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Los elementos registrados son: " << endl;
        for (int i=0; i<x; i++){
            cout << i+1 << " --> " << cliente[i] << endl;
        }
        cout << "\n";
        system("pause");
        cout << "\n\'0\' para terminar. \n"<<"\'1\' para otro pedido: ";
        cin >> repetir;
        cout << "\n";
        
    }else{
        cout<<"El numero de items, debe ser distinto.\nRango es entre \'0\' y \'10\'\n\n";
        system("pause");
    }
} while (repetir == 1);
            
cout<<"Fin de Programa"<<endl;
getch();
return 0;
```

}

Dejo las 2 opciones sea char o string.
Slds.